# C# CheckedListBox how to manipulate checked data?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys new to C# and I am trying to setup a GUI, all I want the GUI to do is have a simple file explorer with a CheckedListBox to represent selected files.
I can get the CheckedListBox to show up and click on files but I'm not sure how to continue from here, most tutorials stop here, or go too advanced with tree view and other things that seem unnecessary for what I am trying to do.
Here is my code:

Any help is appreciated and if you guys could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

EDIT:
To rephrase my question:

I want the user to select files through the CheckedListBox (user input stops here), and for those selected files to be put in a list that my code can manipulate.
Not sure how to accomplish this after my first foreach loop (which adds all files in the selected directory to the CheckedListBox for user selection).

The second foreach loop is an attempt at this, manipulating the files so that they output their filenames after being selected. However no Messagebox shows up and I assume that their is a disconnect between the user selecting files and the codes attempt at manipulating said files.

Second Edit:
I think I figured it out I made a second button and from here it looks like I can manipulate the chosen files however I want.
Currently the code is working the way I would expect it to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SelectFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fbd.SelectedPath);
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file);
            }
        }
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list_all_excelfiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            list_all_excelfiles.Add(item);
            MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(item));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on what you want to happen?

Comment: `foreach (string item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                // do something with item
            }`

Comment: Where you want to go from here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I will edit my question. Using the CheckedListBox I want to be able to: 1.Select .txt/.csv files using the CheckedListBox 2. Have these "checked" files collected into a list so I can manipulate them with the rest of my code

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have edited my question

Comment: at the point of your comment before the list<string> you have no user interaction. You've just filled the checkedListBox. In other words CheckedItems contains nothing and therefore the foreach is skipped over.

Comment: @CharlesMay I don't understand why you say there is no user interaction. When I start the program the user can: Hit a button which allows them to browse through a file explorer for the folder containing their files, when the folder of the users choosing is selected all files in said folder are displayed in the CheckedListBox and can be checked or unchecked. Sounds like user interaction to me. And I don't believe checkeditems is empty I just made a second button which contains the loop in question and It displays files that have been selected by the user. I will post my code so you can see it

Comment: slap a break point on that line and hover over checked items and look at the count. What I'm saying is you have a button click that opens the browser, populates the list and then checks for checked items which at that point the user hasn't been able to interact with. Stepping through that button click event and looking at the collections and values of variables will tell you a lot. And what do you mean by post your code? isn't that what we're looking at here? EDIT: OK, now you have a second button doing the check on the checkeditems which should be more likely to produce an expected result.

Comment: @CharlesMay The list is not populated until the user chooses a file, this is how the code runs: User hits button, Browse for folder pops open, user selects folder through the 
FolderBrowserDialog window, once folder is chosen CheckedListBox is populated with files, User can now check files, after selecting files user can hit second button and the selected files are displayed -- indicating that they have been collected by my instantiated list.

Comment: @CharlesMay I added more code

Comment: Yes, I see that and that would allow for user interaction prior to iterating through the checkeditems. So I assume this is working for you now???.

Answer (score 0):

First i advice you to assign `Value member` and `Display member` for each item.

- Display Member will be visible to user
- Value Member will we use in code

To do this first create simple custom class

```
public class Int_String
{
    public int _int { get; set; }
    public string _string { get; set; }
}
```

`Be careful  because get; set; part is important to be there since if not code will not work`

Now what you need to do is create list of items with custom class like this

```
class YourForm : Form
{
    List<Int_String> myList = new List<Int_String>(); //Create list of our custom class

    public YourForm()
    {
        PopulateMyList();
    }

    private void PopulateMyList()
    {
        //Here read from database or get data somehow and populate our list like this
        //I will populate it manually but you do it in foreach loop

        myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 0, _string = "First Item" });
        myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 1, _string = "Second Item" });
        myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 2, _string = "Third Item" });
    }
}
```

After that you need to assign this list to your `checkedListBox` which you will do like this:

```
public YourForm()
{
    PopulateMyList();
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = myList;
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "_string";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "_int";
}
```

And now when you can manipulate with checked items like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(checkedListBox1.Items[i].CheckedState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        int itemValueMember = (checkedListBox1.Items[i] as Int_String)._int; 
        int itemDisplayMember = (checkedListBox1.Items[i] as Int_String)._string;

        //Use these two vars for whatever you need
    }
}
```

TWO IMPORTANT TIPS:

- I am not sure for this one since i am writing all this from head but i think that visual studio will not show you that there is `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` for `checkedBox` component BUT also it will not show error. Reason is that they have hidden in intentionally for idk what reason but it will work.
- You are able to assign `Display` and `Value` member to a lot of components in winforms BUT for some reason `checkedListBox` is specific. It is specific because you MUST first assign `DataSource` to it and then tell it `checkedListBox.DisplayMember = "_string" .....`. For new guy you will ask why it is important. Simple answer is create custom list for test and add 10k items inside it and then first declare `datasource` and after it `Display` and `Value` member. Test how long form will need to load (get out of freeze state). After that do everything same but first declare `Display` and `Value` member and then assign `datasource` and test again. I am telling this from head without testing but before when i needed about 5k rows with 1st solution it took me about 30 sec and second < 1 sec. If you want to know more about it google it but for now this is pretty much info for you.